# How do I login with my username and password with discord.py? (2019)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a status changer and embedded message sender for myself, and I can't get my discord user token for some bizarre reason, so I want to login with a email and password, is it possible?

Comment: While this has been asked before, they don't work anymore that's why I'm asking this question

Answer (score 0):

Self-Bots are against the [Discord TOS](https://github.com/RayzrDev/SharpBot/issues/116)

Comment: That isn't helpful at all. Hopefully someone else who knows how help.